# Determine the domain and range of the function? any help would be much appreciated.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine the domain and range of the function? any help would be much appreciated.
$y\,\, = \,\,4\cos 3\left( {x\,\, + \,\,1} \right)\,\, - \,\,3$

Comment: Why the `probability` tag?

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined for all $x$. So the domain is the set of all real numbers.

The cosine function takes on all values between $-1$ and $1$, inclusive. So $4\cos(3(x+1))$ takes on all values between $-4$ and $4$. It follows that our function takes on all values between $-7$ and $1$. The range is the interval $[-7,1]$, or equivalently the set of all $x$ such that $-7\le x\le 1$.